# PropertyAccessor error

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook 2007 add-in made in Visual Basic with Visual Studio 2010. I developed this quite a long time ago and it has always worked fine. I detect embedded images using the attachment PropertyAccessor. I now have to go back and make some changes and am running into the following problem. Attempting get the property now gives me the following error (it never did before)
`The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37140003" is unknown or cannot be found.` Other properties I can get fine. I have seen other posts with the same error which mention that the PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN property is not set. I don't understand this as the attachment is an ordinary jpg sent by me from another account. If I build the add-in and install in Outlook 2016 it works just fine. What I find strange is that it used to work with no errors. I don't know if it makes any difference but it is running in VirtualBox.
Any Ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Edit your code into the question body and you might get some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` behavior changed (in Outlook 2010?) when it comes to properties that are not present - `GetProperty` will now raise an exception instead of returning null.

You need to expect and handle that exception - no MAPI property should be expected to be present. In your particular case, missing `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN` is the same as `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN` == false.

Take a look at the available MAPI properties on the attachment in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select the message, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on the attachment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. This must have happened in a MS Update to Outlook 2007 as the program hasn’t changed since being written. According to OutlookSpy there isn’t a PR_ATTACH_FLAGS or a PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID. As I extract embedded images by checking PR_ATTACH_FLAGS = 4 I will have to do some more testing.

Comment: PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID is not a sufficient check - HTML body can refer to an image by its file name. You really need to look at the HTML to see which files should be treated as images.